# swipe with one finger and two finger swipe on the same UIView subclass

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a custom implementation of UITableViewCell.
The UITableViewCell can be swiped to the left or the right.
I use a UIPanGestureRecognizer for the same.

```
UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
        recognizer.delegate = self;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

           }

#pragma mark - horizontal pan gesture methods
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [gestureRecognizer translationInView:[self superview]];
    // Check for horizontal gesture
    if (fabsf(translation.x) > fabsf(translation.y)) {
        return YES;
     }
    return NO;
}

-(void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    // if the gesture has just started, record the current centre location
        // SOME CODE
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // translate the center
        //SOME CODE
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // the frame this cell would have had before being dragged
        //SOME CODE
    }
}
```

Now I want to be able to support two finger swipe on on the entire screen such that even if a two finger swipe is done on a UITableViewCell, the above code is not triggered.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you sure your "Check for horizontal gesture" logic is correct?

Answer (score 1):

If you set the `maximumNumberOfTouches` on your gesture recognizer to `1`, it will no longer accept multi-finger swipes:

```
UIGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
recognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
```